# cURL post to PayPal succeeds while HTML Form post and RunScope post fail

Tags: forms, post, curl, paypal, runscope

I'm currently developing an integration with PayPal's Payflow Pro Gateway.  I'm sending a request to PayPal to get their "Secure Token" so that I can use that to do the real transaction.  A sample I found on SO works via cURL, but the original HTML Form POST and RunScope tests I ran did **not** work.

Here is the cURL command:

```
curl https://pilot-payflowpro.paypal.com -kd "PARTNER=PayPal&VENDOR=*****&USER=*****&PWD=*****&TRXTYPE=A&AMT=40&CREATESECURETOKEN=Y&SECURETOKENID=*******&SILENTTRAN=TRUE"
```

Per the [cURL documentation](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

The -k option is:

> "(SSL) This option explicitly allows curl to perform "insecure" SSL
>   connections and transfers. All SSL connections are attempted to be
>   made secure by using the CA certificate bundle installed by default.
>   This makes all connections considered "insecure" fail unless -k,
>   --insecure is used."

The -d option is:

> "(HTTP) Sends the specified data in a POST request to the HTTP server,
>   in the same way that a browser does when a user has filled in an HTML
>   form and presses the submit button. This will cause curl to pass the
>   data to the server using the content-type
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Compare to -F, --form."
>
> -d, --data is the same as --data-ascii. To post data purely binary, you should instead use the --data-binary option. To URL-encode the
>   value of a form field you may use --data-urlencode.
>
> If any of these options is used more than once on the same command
>   line, the data pieces specified will be merged together with a
>   separating &-symbol. Thus, using '-d name=daniel -d skill=lousy' would
>   generate a post chunk that looks like 'name=daniel&skill=lousy'.
>
> If you start the data with the letter @, the rest should be a file
>   name to read the data from, or - if you want curl to read the data
>   from stdin. The contents of the file must already be URL-encoded.
>   Multiple files can also be specified. Posting data from a file named
>   'foobar' would thus be done with --data @foobar. When --data is told
>   to read from a file like that, carriage returns and newlines will be
>   stripped out.

That works great and returns this response:

```
RESULT=0&SECURETOKEN=*****&SECURETOKENID=*****&RESPMSG=Approved
```

#### HTML Form POST

However, what I perceive to be the same request fails in the following HTML form POST:

```
<input type="hidden" name="TRXTYPE" value="A" />
<input type="hidden" name="SILENTTRAN" value="TRUE" />

<input type="hidden" name="AMT" value="40" />

<input type="hidden" name="CREATESECURETOKEN" value="Y" />
<input type="hidden" name="SECURETOKENID" value="*****" />

<input type="submit" value="Get Secure Token" />
```

That gives me "*The connection was reset*" in FireFox.

*I also tried using jQuery to POST the data using $.ajax(), but I received a 200 response with no data in it.*

#### Runscope

When I enter the above parameters into [RunScope](https://www.runscope.com/), I get:

```
RESULT=1&SECURETOKENID=*****&RESPMSG=User authentication failed
```

Which doesn't make any sense!

I was thinking that PayPal is either doing something with examining the user agent, or request headers, but I don't have any real idea.  Can anyone shed some light on this behavior?

Comment: Why would you send raw calls via form to the API? Try posting to a script and let the script do the work for you

Comment: This was just for testing, it's not critical, I'm just trying to understand why these other methods fails.